# foreach array_slice not working

Tags: php, foreach

I try to display only the first 3 items of a foreach, but for some reason my code does not seem to work.

It works fine with the default code: `<?php foreach ($rma->getItemCollection() as $item):?>`

What am I missing?

CODE:

```
<?php $items = $rma->getItemCollection();
$item =  array_slice($items, 0, 3);
foreach($item as $itm): ?>
    <li class="order-row-item">
        <div class="order-row-product">
            <div class="order-row-product-image">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($itm->getProduct(), 'thumbnail')->resize(85) ?>" border="0" />
            </div>
            <div class="order-row-product-name">
                <?php echo substr(Mage::helper('rma')->getOrderItemLabel($itm), 0, 30) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Does not seem to work? Explain please.

Comment: What is the output of doing `print_r($items);` ... as this may be an associative array, which won't work with array_slice directly.

Comment: @u_mulder Sorry. It does not work, because there is non <li> items displayed, so it skips all items.

Comment: So, `print_r($items)`, `print_r($item)`, see what is wrong

Comment: @u_mulder Both `print_r($items)`, `print_r($item)` does not give any output inside the foreach. Removing the `array_slice` also solves the problem and it gives output

Comment: Now check __before__ the `foreach`

Comment: Also if `$items` is __not__ array, then it's useless to use `array_slice`

Comment: @u_mulder That seems to be the problem, it is not array. Is there a other way to only display the first 3 items?

Comment: Use a counter and break

Comment: @u_mulder Can you give me a example of the counter code?

Comment: `if ($counter == 3) break;`

Comment: @u_mulder! Thanks a lot, works fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of result of `$rma->getItemCollection();` is **not** array, but some object, which implements [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface, you can use a counter:

```
<?php 
$items = $rma->getItemCollection();
$counter = 0;
foreach($items as $item): ?>
    <li>...</li>
<?php
    $counter++;
    if ($counter == 3) {
        break;
    }
endforeach;
```

Other way can be specifying a limit for query which is done under the hood in `getItemCollection()`.

Answer (score -2):

try this code

```
<?php
 $items = $rma->getItemCollection();
 $item =  array_slice($items, 0, 3);
 foreach($item as $itm){
 echo'
    <li class="order-row-item">
        <div class="order-row-product">
            <div class="order-row-product-image">
                <img src="'.
                 $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($itm->getProduct(), 
               'thumbnail')->resize(85).' border="0" />
            </div>
            <div class="order-row-product-name">'.
              substr(Mage::helper('rma')->getOrderItemLabel($itm), 0, 30).'
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>';}
?>`
```

Comment: Explain your answer.

Comment: And the difference is?

Comment: You may provide a documentation with your code for better understanding, it doesn't mean anything this way.